# How to get month from the date field in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using this

```
SELECT  CONVERT(INT(4), DateOfDeposit, 100) FROM ABC
```

It gives the months like jan, feb but i want the no. representation like 1 for jan,2 for feb.
How?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  Month(DateOfDeposit) FROM ABC
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813%28v=sql.100%29.aspx